# Sort numbers in digit order

Tags: c++, sorting

I know that when the numbers are input as strings and sorted normally, I would get the correct output. But can someone explain how/why this is happening?

Example test case:

Input:

```
100 1 10 2 21 20
```

Output:

```
1 10 100 2 20 21
```

Comment: If you read a list of numbers, why don't you read them *as numbers*?

Comment: Maybe you compare the first digit with the others then the 2nd and so on... can't tell you without your code

Comment: "can someone explain how/why this is happening?" - for *exactly* the reason you stated: they're *strings*. The "values" being sorted a sequences of characters, compared one at a time lexicographically.

Comment: It's because the sorting method on strings takes place per-character. `a` comes before `aa` comes before `ab` comes before `b` comes before `ba`. Replace 0 1 and 2 with a, b and c respectively and it'll make more sense.

Comment: **numbers are input as strings and sorted normally,I would get the correct output**. This is incorrect. Do you think Numbers are in sorted form here `1 10 100 2 20 21`?

Comment: Efficient way to sort number is to read this strings and populate as modified prefix tree. Root node has 10 buckets [0,1,...9] then as you encounter digit in a string append this nodes with relevant [node,count,end-marker,nextnode]. Key is to exploit Numbers as String, apply string sorting.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude first i tried to sort them in digits order using numbers..then i came across this solution using strings but wasn't able to understand how it works..thats the reason :))

Comment: @sameerkn "sorted in digits order"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digits, when considered as characters, are handled the same as alphabetical characters. (i.e. they have a relative lexicographical order, which is the same as their ordering based on ascending value)

In effect, when you're handling integers as string,s you may consider digits 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 to be letters 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'. Consequently, sorting the input can be thought of as sorting strings.

Your original input;

```
100 1 10 2 21 20
```

can then be considered as;

```
baa b ba c cb ca
```

for which the appropriate ordering would be;

```
b ba baa c ca cb
```

If you switch back the values, you may see that this is the output you provided in your question, namely;

```
1 10 100 2 20 21
```

Comment: Thanks @ilim but I'm not able to upvote since my rep<15 hehehe

Comment: @theavatar You are the author of the question. Among the provided answers, you should be able to choose one of them as the answer to your question, even if you can not upvote or downvote.

Comment: @theavatar You may consider taking [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

That is just how default [lexicographical string comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) works.

What you are probably looking for is called [*natural sort*](https://github.com/jpakkane/naturalsort):

> Natural order means sorting strings so that embedded numbers are treated as numbers. This means that if you use natural order for sorting you get this:
>
> ```
>  1 one
>  2 two
>  3 three
>  10 ten
> ```
>
> Instead of the default sort behaviour:
>
> ```
> 1 one
> 10 ten
> 2 two
> 3 three
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Reading a list of numbers, sorting them and then printing them out is *extremely* easy in C++ once you know the "secret".

The "secret" is to use the functionality that exist in the standard library. In this case (reading numbers, sorting them, printing them out) you need to know about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator), [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator).

Then you could do something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // Create a vector containing numbers read from std::cin
    std::vector<int> number(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
                            std::istream_iterator<int>());

    // Sort the numbers
    std::sort(begin(numbers), end(numbers));

    // Print all the numbers in the vector to std::cout
    std::copy(begin(numbers), end(numbers),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```